# How to handle text columns with ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, odbc, sybase, smalltalk

Previously we have been using sybase with an **Adaptive Server Enterprise** driver.
Currently we are in the process of switching to MSSQL and will then be using an **ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server**.

We keep getting `Invalid Descriptor Index` errors we didn't get with sybase when calling SQLGetData on an unbound column with index `i` while the highest bound column has index `i+n`. This makes sense according to the [SQLGetData doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlgetdata-function#diagnostics)

On the other hand, what isn't making sense to me is that `SQLGetInfo` with type 81(`SQL_GETDATA_EXTENSIONS`) returns an empty string for both drivers. I Would expect the sybase one to return something signifying that it has the property `SQL_GD_ANY_COLUMN`

My question is:
Is there a way to give the **ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server** the `SQL_GD_ANY_COLUMN` property?
If not, how should one then handle text columns of varying lengths(Shouldn't bind those with `SQLBind`?)?

I'm very new with this so any insight appreciated:)

Comment: Which Smalltalk dialect are you using?

Comment: I'm currently using VSE.

Comment: Ok. Then I would recommend posting the question to the VSE list: "Using Visual Smalltalk for Windows/Enterprise (VSWE-L@LISTSERV.DFN.DE)" <VSWE-L@listserv.dfn.de>.

Comment: We are using bind, yes. For VARCHAR we have something called SQLPartitionableBuffer that we read repeatedly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the driver behaviour. I recommend that you make repeated calls to the SQLGetData ODBC function for the text/varchar(max) columns

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We ended up just redoing most queries so that text fields end up last in the Select statements. To avoid the invalid descriptor index error that is.